# My SSAS Dimension Hierarchy is not showing correctly

Tags: ssas, hierarchy, cube

I have a dimension called Dim_DueAnalysis in a multidimensional cube.

The underlying table looks like this (only a subset of the data is here):

```
DueAnalysis_Key  DueAnalysisID  DueAnalysisDays    DueAnalysisIntervalWeeks  DueAnalysisInterval   DueAnalysisDueOverdue
1052             26             Overdue by 26 days Overdue by 3 weeks        Overdue by 1-30 days  Overdue
1053             27             Overdue by 27 days Overdue by 3 weeks        Overdue by 1-30 days  Overdue
1054             28             Overdue by 28 days Overdue by 4 weeks        Overdue by 1-30 days  Overdue
1055             29             Overdue by 29 days Overdue by 4 weeks        Overdue by 1-30 days  Overdue
1056             30             Overdue by 30 days Overdue by 4 weeks        Overdue by 1-30 days  Overdue
1057             31             Overdue by 31 days Overdue by 4 weeks        Overdue by 31-60 days Overdue
```

This table looks fine and dandy.

My dimension in the cube has a hierarchy:

```
Due Analysis Key => Due Analysis Days => Due Analysis Interval Weeks => Due Analysis Interval => Due Analysis Due Overdue
                 => Due Analysis Day Number                          => Due Analysis ID sort
```

All my Relationship Types are Flexible. But still my dimension looks like this when I browse it in my Analysis Database:

```
Overdue
- Overdue by 1-30 days
  ...
  - Overdue by 3 weeks
    - Overdue by 21 days
      ...
    - Overdue by 27 days
- Overdue by 31-60 days
  - Overdue by 4 weeks
    - Overdue by 28 days
    - Overdue by 29 days
      ...
```

As you might have noticed, days 28-30 are in the 31-60 days interval.

What I want is that part of "Overdue by 4 weeks" (days 28-30) is in the Overdue in 1-30 Days hierarchy and not in the Overdue by 31-60 days. But "Overdue by 4 weeks" should also be present in the Overdue by 31-60 days as days 31-34 should be present there.

I thought that it was just a matter of setting my relationship type to "Flexible" instead of "Rigid" but that has not solved my problem.

I am not sure what further information is needed in order to solve this case so please ask about how certain properties etc are.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your dimension attribute hierarchy, its design is not 100% clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah of course - I had to create another column specifying which week AND day interval my data was in. By using that column I got my hierarchy correct.